# Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, script

I have an exe which produces an output with some parameter, and from that output I want the integer portion to be stored in a file like below:

`C:\MyExe -param` gives an o/p `123abc`, so `123` should be stored in a file. How can we achieve this through Windows command line?

Comment: Do you have to use cmd.exe or is PowerShell ok?

Comment: We have to use only cmd.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as elegant as dbenham’s answer, but it is pure Windows. 
If your program’s output always looks like your example
(a sequence of digits immediately followed by a lower case letter, and then followed by other stuff),
this will work:

```
for /f "delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" %x in ('C:\MyExe -param') do echo %x > out.txt
```

Notes:

- If the last digit might be followed by a character other than a lower case letter (even a space),
  include all possible delimiter characters in the `delims=` string.
- The above command will work if typed into an interactive Command Prompt. 
  To use it in a batch file (i.e., a Command Prompt script), change `%x` to `%%x` (both occurrences).
- The above command will execute the `echo %x > out.txt` subcommand once
  for each line of output from `C:\MyExe -param` that contains at least one delimiter character. 
  If your program writes only that one line, no problem. 
  If you program writes multiple such lines, e.g.,

  ```
  5gold rings
  4calling birds
  3french hens
  2turtle doves
  1partridge
  ```

  it will overwrite the file each time, and you’ll end up with only the last value.
  If you want to capture all the numbers, add parentheses, like this:

  ```
  (for /f "delims=abc…xyz" %x in ('C:\MyExe -param') do echo %x) > MyOutputFile.txt
  ↑                                                            ↑
  ```

  so the entire command (up through the `echo %x`) will be treated as a single command, and the redirection (`>`) will occur only once. 
  Alternatively, just change the `>` to `>>`, and the outputs will accumulate
  (but also, anything that was in the file before will still be there,
  with the new output appended to it).

Comment: Awesome Man, Somehow it solved my requirement. Thanks a lot for the help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not trivial with pure batch, but it is if you use [REPL.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) that performs a regular expression search/replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout. It is pure script that will run on any modern Windows machine from XP onward.

```
c:\myExe -param | repl "(\d*).*" $1 >out.txt
```